# psql -U someuser -W some_db doesn't respect the password?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've got a database and a role I set up through PSQL like...

```
CREATE ROLE someuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'S0m3u53r';
CREATE DATABASE some_db OWNER someuser;
```

I noticed that I can enter any password I want when I try to connect as that user.  Below is the output of a psql session where I entered "fizzbuzz" as the password.  Psql just let me in, never bothering to check the password.

```
$ psql -U someuser -W some_db
Password for user someuser:
psql (9.4.1)
Type "help" for help.

some_db=> select current_user;
 current_user
--------------
 someuser
(1 row)
some_db=>
```

Why doesn't psql enforce that user password?  I expected it to reject me somehow when I entered the wrong password but psql doesn't seem to care.  I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The postgres user authentication settings are stored in a file called `pg_hba.conf`.

Your current settings allow anyone connecting locally, *via unix sockets* to be `trusted`, i.e. no password will be required at login. As long as the user exists in the database, it will be allowed to login.

You can change that to `md5` or `password` for local connections For connections over the network, `password` isn't sufficiently secure, as it sends the raw textual password.

Find your `pg_hba.conf` file. Near the bottom of the file is a line that reads like:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
```

Change it to

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
```

The `pg_hba.conf` file's location depends on what system you're on. On Ubuntu, the file would be in

```
/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf
```

On OSX (installed via homebrew), the file's path is

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf
```

To find out more about authentication in postgres, see the [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)